# Clion: How to configure clion when Opening existing folder there is no debug and run menu?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, clion

I'm using CLion 2021.1.1 version. I'm a new user. I've done some cpp programs on codeblocks. But Whenever I open an existing folder the files are showing but there is no debug option. It says Add configuration. There is no run option. I've added MingW in buil, execution, Deployment -> Toolchains-> mingw but still it says add configuration. I've close it open new projects in CPP but still getting add configuration. How can open the existing folder and it has many cpp files that I can run each and every cpp file. How can achieve this?
sometimes I get this error:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2021.1.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:66 (message):
The C compiler

"C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe"

is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: O:/1.Fourth Semester/Programming/Algorithm/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_d8b71/fast && C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8b71.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8b71.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'O:/1.Fourth Semester/Programming/Algorithm/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8b71.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8b71.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c "O:\1.Fourth Semester\Programming\Algorithm\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
CMakeFiles\cmTC_d8b71.dir\build.make:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8b71.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_d8b71.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'O:/1.Fourth Semester/Programming/Algorithm/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Makefile:139: recipe for target 'cmTC_d8b71/fast' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_d8b71/fast] Error 2

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project
```

Someone help, please

Comment: In CLion, you have to provide a CMakeLists.txt file. It is written in the CMake Language

Comment: The error message could also indicate that there is either something wrong with your MinGW installation or the toolchain in CLion is set up inappropriately. You can also see if PATH is set properly.